# common directory for all hosts in a shared hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, directory, share

I have many many many domains in a single machine. (redhat apache php mysql) and all have own admin pages. but when I update admin code it is very difficult to update all folders. then ı decided to use single code base for all my domains and in an outside of the document root of the virtual hosts. 
ı tried ln (symbolic links) but it says dir is not accessible altough I gave all necessary rights. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

use an alias for each vhost entry

```
Alias /admin/ /path/to/admin/files
```

So when they go to domain.com/admin/ it will serve files from your /path/to...

Comment: I did. but apache logs give me this line.
[<a date>] [error] [client <an ip>] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed opening '/path/to/admin/files/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: ahh.. you did change /path/to/admin/files right?

Comment: sure, for sec reasons, i have changed those real log lines for your example. I also tried include_path in php.ini and php_value include_path in vhost.conf file

Comment: @edib: if /path/to/admin/file is not in the php include_path it will always fail, try to check that include_path settings value in a temporary phpinfo() page, and grep the source code for any ini_set (or use pĥp_admin_value in the vhost so nobody can alter this setting).